# External HDD (NTFS) goes offline in few minutes

Tags: hard-drive

I am new to Ubuntu(v18.04.1 LTS), please bear with me.
I have a Windows internal Hdd (NTFS), that i converted to external using a USB casing. The hard drive gets recognized as soon as i plug it in, and within 2-3 minutes just disappears. I managed another hdd and the same issue. I tried  these hdds in a Windows 10 system and it worked fine:(

Comment: Even when you run `sudo lsblk -f` on the Ubuntu you don't see them? Again are the contact points (usb port) working very well?

Comment: i havent tried that command, will try it now. Contact points are clean and the hard drive is detected and works for few minutes.

Comment: Tried the command, it throws, sudo:1sblk: command not found.
Also, i tried another seagate casing and on that the hard drive works like a charm.

Comment: it's not a `1` it's an `l`(el, as in light) pls try again!

Comment: Thank you George, i connected the hard drive, ran the command, and this time, it hasnt gone offline.What could be the reason? power saving?

Comment: And it happened again, this time after i copied like a few GBs from that HDD. Running the command doesnt list the drive after it disappears,

Comment: Check the connector and the port make sure their both okay..

Comment: For some HDD, the enclosure requires more power than a single USB-A connector to power it. If the external enclosure comes with a cable with two USB-A connector, you should use that to power the enclosure. Note: Not all HDD draw extra power, many HDD will just work with single USB-A connection.

Comment: @Bernard, yes the HDD enclosure has an external power adapter. When i use the same HDD in a Seagate enclosure it works fine. So, i copied the data, then formatted the hdd from NTFS to FAT32, and then used the same inexpensive hdd enclosure, it seems to be working fine.

Comment: And the issue, reappeared after 20mins this time, the drive just goes off, its like some incompatibility with this enclosure:( Dont see a lose connection as it works fine on windows pc.

Comment: @Denser I have an enclosure that works fine with WD drives but having problem with one or two Seagate drives in powering up. Some 2.5" drives draw more power on startup, other may draw a bit more power during use. Some enclosure may be more sensitive to power draw and require power from two USB port, usually using the supplied Y-connector cable, USB data --> USB data + USB secondary power.